# Screen sharing not painting properly on client

Tags: 11.10, vnc

I cannot get the screen sharing utility in Ubuntu 11.10 to work properly. When I connect, I get the initial screen, but no updates. When I connect to my Ubuntu box via a laptop, I can see the mouse moving, but when I click on anything, the screen does not update.

I can disconnect, reconnect and then see the updated screen, but it does not automatically refresh. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The VNC server cannot handle the 3D effects. The VNC client actually controls the desktop, but updates don't come back to the VNC client screen. To get the updates to come back to the client do the following:

On the server side, log out. Now change the session type. After you have entered your user name,  press the wheel in the upper right corner of the login box and choose "Ubuntu 2D" as the session type.

Now when you log back in, VNC clients will see the changes they make. Any session type that disables 3D effects should work.